# Sharing classes across different web services proxy classes

Tags: wcf, wsdl.exe, wcf-proxy

I am writting wcf services in .net 3.5 framework with **basicHttpBinding** and hosting it in the IIS 6.0 ( windows 2003).

I have 3 different services ( AuthenticationSerice, Dataserviceservice, ReportingService), there few classess which are shared among these service.
 My problem is When I am generating proxy classes  for three wcf/web services, it generating three different proxy classes (common classes are not shared accross the proxy class).

**Is it possible to generate on proxy class for all three wcf/web services with sharing class types?**

Note: The client is developed in .net 2.0 framework. So I need to use WSDL to generate the proxy classes.

nRk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, I found solution for my problem... 
I am able to generate one class with wsdl.exe with sharing common class types.

wsdl /sharetypes /namespace:TestNamespace http://192.168.0.109/xxxx/Service1.svc?wsdl http://192.168.0.109/xxxx/Service2.svc?wsdl http://192.168.0.109/xxxx/Service3.svc?wsdl

 the follwowing link contain same question.
[wsdl.exe /sharetypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489542/wsdl-exe-sharetypes)

nrk